# Knowing which proxy is used in rotating proxy

Tags: proxy

I'm using a webshare.io rotating proxy, which has a single endpoint address and automatically assigns a random proxy for each request.

Some of my proxies are getting blocked. How can I know which ones? The proxy address is invisible to me as I'm querying a single endpoint for all of them. I haven't seen any relevant X-Proxy in the response, and the target site does not return the source ip of the request.